# How Do I Log The Post Request for A Logout in The Default Scaffolded C# ASP.NET Core Identity Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I need to get the exact request being sent from the browser to the server in the default dotnet C# asp.net core identity razor pages. This is the default logout function in `Logout.cshtml.cs`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    if (returnUrl != null)
    {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

So if I wanted to use Postman to do this function as a post request, `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();`, excatly what would I put into Postman as headers and body? How do I log exactly what `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();` is sending to the server?

Comment: If you want to call post  handler in postman,it needs to add antiforgery token.If you only want to get data from handler,you can try to create a get handler,and add `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync()` to it,so that you don't need to add antiforgery token in postman.